# How to create a loop for this program to repeat the game if there is a tie

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

i have created this code and i am trying to create a loop for it to repeat and discard 10 cards then show the 11th if the result is tie but i dont know how to do that correctly.

```
public class War {


public static void main(String args[]) {
 Card player = new Card();
    Card computer = new Card();


    final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;

    char[] su = {'C', 'H', 'D', 'S'};
    char randomSuit = su[(char) (Math.random() * (su.length - 1))];
    char randomSuit2 = su[(char) (Math.random() * (su.length - 1))];


    
    int playervalue = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1);
    int computervalue = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1);



    System.out.println("Player: " + playervalue + " of " + randomSuit);

    player.getValue(randomSuit, playervalue);

    System.out.println("Computer: " + computervalue + " of " + randomSuit2);
    computer.getValue(randomSuit2, computervalue);


    player.setValue(randomSuit, playervalue);

    computer.setValue(randomSuit2, computervalue);

    if (playervalue > computervalue)
        System.out.println("Results: Player won");
    else if (computervalue > playervalue)
        System.out.println("Results: Computer won");

    else
            System.out.println("Results: Equal");


        }
}
```

this is the class Card

```
public class Card {

char suit;
int number;



public void setValue(char su, int num) {
    suit = su;
    number = num;


    if (number <= 1 || number >= 13) {

    } else {

        number = 1;
    }

}


public void getValue(char su, int num) {

    switch (su) {
        case 'C':

            break;

        case 'H':

            break;
        case 'D':

            break;

        case 'S':

            break;



    }

    }
}
```

Any advices on how to do it or get started? im pretty much new to coding so this is my first program.

Comment: you can use the do{}while() for that, i think :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and it works as you want it to.

Here's what I changed and why:

1. Declared variable as `Global/Class` variable, so that they can be accessed from any method.

(You have to declare a variable or a method as `static` if you are calling the method
or using the variable in `main()` method because it is also `static`)

2. Created a separate method `shuffleCard()` which assign card to player and computer, so that you don't have write the same code again and again.
3. Created a separate method `printResult` which will check player and computer cards and then print the result accordingly.

**Don't worry** if you don't understand the meaning of these changes, just use the code and continue learning `JAVA`, you will soon learn about methods, variables and all.

Modified code:

```
public class War 
{

  static Card player = new Card();
  static Card computer = new Card();  
  
  static final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
  static char[] su = {'C', 'H', 'D', 'S'};
  
  static int playervalue;
  static int computervalue;
    
public static void shuffleCard()
{
    char randomSuit = su[(char) (Math.random() * (su.length - 1))];
    char randomSuit2 = su[(char) (Math.random() * (su.length - 1))];

    playervalue = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1);
    computervalue = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1);

    System.out.println("Player: " + playervalue + " of " + randomSuit);
    player.getValue(randomSuit, playervalue);

    System.out.println("Computer: " + computervalue + " of " + randomSuit2);
    computer.getValue(randomSuit2, computervalue);

    player.setValue(randomSuit, playervalue);
    computer.setValue(randomSuit2, computervalue);  
    printResult();
}        

public static void printResult()
{
 if (playervalue > computervalue)
        System.out.println("Results: Player Won");
 else if (computervalue > playervalue)
        System.out.println("Results: Computer Won");
 else{
        System.out.println("Results: Equal");
        System.out.println("Let's shuffle the cards again");
        shuffleCard();
 }         
}        

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  shuffleCard();
}
}
```

**If you want to know**, here's how this program works now:

1. The `main()` method call the `shuffleCard()` method which generate random cards and assign the value to `player` and `computer`.
2. Then, at the end of `shuffleCard()` method, `printResult()` method is called. It compares player and computer cards and print result accordingly.
3. The **important thing** you should notice is that, in the `printResult()` method, you can see that, **if the player card and computer card are same**, in other words, the result is tie, then the `shuffleCard()` method is **called again**, that is, the program goes back to point 1.
4. Now, the `shuffleCard()` method will again generate random cards and assign the value to `player` and `computer`. And then, it will again call the `printResult()` method.

(Here, you can either shuffle the cards again or you can show the 11th card by removing the `shuffleCard()` method at the end of `printResult()` method and adding the code to show the 11th card. I added `shuffleCard()` to demonstrate a proper loop.)

So, this loop will continue until player card and computer card are different.

Thank you.